# "Printing" tab delimited text to a .txt file with Visual Studio 2012 (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

Ok, I know I am using an OLD and outdated version of Visual Basic so please don't pester me about this.
I have a form with a listbox on it that gets populated with up to 25 words ranging from 3 to 10 characters in length.  When the user clicks a button on the form, I would like to generate a tab delimited list of those words - 5 across, centered and left justified to a text file;

```
                       word1     word2     word3     word4     word5
                       word6     word7     word8     word9     word10
```

I cannot get the TAB function to work properly for me because of the length of the words.  Here are some 10 letter words that printed.  Notice how the 2nd to the 5th words printed skewed;

```
           EASTERLIES        EASTERNERS    EAVESDROPS    EBULLIENCE    EBULLITION
           ECCENTRICS     ECHELONING    ECHINODERM    ECOLOGICAL    ECOLOGISTS
           ECONOMICAL     ECONOMISTS    ECONOMIZED    ECONOMIZER    ECONOMIZES
           ECOSYSTEMS     ECUMENICAL    ECUMENISMS    ECUMENISTS    EDGINESSES
           EDIBLENESS     EDITORIALS    EDITORSHIP    EDUCATEDLY    EDUCATIONS
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
     For wordnum As Integer = 0 To (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        num += 1
        tmpWrd = Trim(ListBox1.Items.Item(wordnum).ToString)

        If num = 1 Then
            Print(FileNum, Space(15))
            Print(FileNum, tmpWrd)
        Else
            Print(FileNum, TAB, tmpWrd)
        End If

        If num = 5 Then
            num = 0
            Print(FileNum, vbNewLine)
        End If

    Next
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe you need to use vbTab or Chr(9) in place of "TAB".  That "TAB" parameter is not necessarily inserting a tab character into the file, it's telling the Print() statement to make its own determinations about where to position the text.  That's not what you're after, I don't believe

Answer (score 0):

Well, after sitting here a few hours I think I figured it out.  It's a rather "old school" approach to this, but it works:

```
    For wordnum As Integer = 0 To (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        num += 1
        tmpWrd = Trim(ListBox1.Items.Item(wordnum).ToString)

        If num = 1 Then
            Print(FileNum, Space(20) & tmpWrd)
        Else
            Print(FileNum, Space((10 - tmpInt) + 3) & tmpWrd)
        End If

        If num = 5 Then
            num = 0
            tmpInt = 0
            Print(FileNum, vbCrLf)
            GoTo nxt
        End If

        tmpInt = Len(tmpWrd)

    nxt:    Next
```

1. I get the first word from the ListBox
2. I check to see if it's the first of the five (5)
3. If so, I print 20 spaces THEN the word to center it on the page
4. Then I check to see if this word is the fifth word
5. If so I: reset the word counter, reset the word length variable, print a carriage return and jump over the line that gets the length of the last word
6. If this isn't the fifth word, I get the length of the word (tmpInt)
7. Loop to get next word
8. Being the second word, I print that word with the difference between 10 and the length of the last word + 3 away from the last one.

Like I said, maybe an unusually long and old way of doing this, but it works!